# Modifying Auto-generated function headers in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, auto-generate

I am trying to modify the auto-generated function headers in Eclipse to produce a slightly different format.

I have code that generates this:

```
/**
 * Method Description...
 * 
 * @method testComments
 * @author David Gauthier
 * @param param1
 * @param param2
 */
function testComments(param1, param2) {

}
```

Here is the code that does it:

```
/**Method Description...
 * 
 * @method ${enclosing_method}
 * @author ${user}
 * ${tags} 
 */
```

This is the result I would like:

```
/**
 * Method Description...
 * 
 * @method testComments
 * @author David Gauthier
 * @param {type} param1 Param Description...
 * @param {type} param2 Param Description...
 */
function testComments(param1, param2) {

}
```

How would I go about doing this?